# LINQ Query based on values in a list?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to filter the entity based on the possibility of a list of integers being passed to the query; however it is also possible that no integers as passed into the query. In the example below If a "status" is passed in as a list of integers, i would want to return all results that contain a matching status (integer)

```
Status As List(Of Integer)
Query as IQueryable(Of db.People) = db.people.asNoTracking.Where(Function(C) c.DeleteFlag = False)
Query = (From q In Query From s In Status Where q.PersonStatus = s)
```

Comment: So what is the question?  Is your code not working?

Comment: @Tim Sorry, Correct does not work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming if you pass in no statuses, that you want all the records, then:

```
query=db.people.Where(Function(c) c.DeleteFlag=False)
if (Status.Any())
  query=query.Where(Function(c) Status.Contains(c.PersonStatus))
```

If you want no records when no statuses are passed in then:

```
if (!Status.Any())
  query=new List(Of people).AsQueryable()
else
  ...
endif
```